# Uninitialized pointer in C is surprisingly working in MinGW

Tags: c, pointers

My friend sent me this code and said  if I could find any problems with this, I examined the code and found that he is using an uninitialized pointer `int *ptr;` and told him that but he said that this code works, so I copied the code and compiled it with gcc which gave me Segmentation fault (core dumped) on execution but he claims that this code works and gave me a screenshot (He is using MinGW in Dev-C++).

So the question is why this code works in MinGW when using a uninitialized pointer should be UB?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int size,i,j,sum=0;
    puts("enter1");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    int arr1[size];
    puts("enter1");
    int *ptr;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        scanf("%d",(ptr+i));
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        sum=sum+*(ptr+i);
    }
    printf("'%d'",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The output (on Dev-C++ using MinGW):
[image: The output]

Comment: Never be "surprised" when invoking *undefined behavior* seems to work. The behavior is, after all, *undefined*. Whomever/whatever told you invoking UB was guaranteed *not* to work, they were grossly mistaken. Undefined means there is *no definition*, so you honestly can make no conclusions as to *what* it will do (or not do). Therefore, the task is to write code that leaves no doubt by adhering strictly to behavior that *is* defined.

Comment: okay, I'll keep that in mind. <3

Comment: Apparently it *just happened* to point to some valid address you could read and write. Your program just overwrote some variables it doesn't care about. If you're unlucky, it will be some variables that your program does care about, causing a crash.

Comment: "_when using a uninitialized pointer should be UB?_? Well, that it works in his case __is__ undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Undefined" doesn't mean "illegal".  It simply means that pretty much any result is possible, *including* appearing to work correctly.  If an uninitialized pointer value corresponds to a writable address that's not currently in use, or if a buffer overflow spills into memory that's otherwise unused, then your code will happily chug along with no outward issues.

And that's **the** most pernicious manifestation of UB, precisely because it *does* appear to work correctly.  And it will continue to appear to work correctly until something in the runtime environment changes, or you make an unrelated change in the code and rebuild, and then suddenly all hell breaks loose and *you have no idea why*.  I've been in that situation more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing uninitialized pointers is undefined behavior. As you and your friend have seen, sometimes this "works", sometimes it segfaults, and on some other machine it could make demons fly out of your nose (and it could change from run to run even on the same machine). It's undefined, the result can be anything. Just because "it works on his machine" (likely a coincidence of stack usage patterns that left a semi-valid memory address on the stack for him to use) doesn't make it right.

Answer (score 0):

when compiled with `gcc`  with the warnings enabled, the compiler outputs:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" -o "untitled2.o" 

untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled2.c:6:9: warning: unused variable ‘arr1’ [-Wunused-variable]
    6 |     int arr1[size];
      |         ^~~~

untitled2.c:3:16: warning: unused variable ‘j’ [-Wunused-variable]
    3 |     int size,i,j,sum=0;
      |                ^

untitled2.c:10:9: warning: ‘ptr’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   10 |         scanf("%d",(ptr+i));
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Compilation finished successfully.
```

so you really have to enable the warnings to get any useful messages from the compiler.

Regarding:

```
Compilation finished successfully.
```

When there are warning messages, then this output only means that the compiler applied some `workaround` to the code, not that the correct code was generated.

also, regarding:

```
int *ptr;
```

This will result in a seg fault event at runtime because it is not pointing to memory that the program owns.

all the above should be fixed before trying to actually run the executable

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. checks for and handles I/O errors

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( void ) 
{
    //int size,i,j,sum=0;
    int size;

    int sum=0;
    
    
    //puts( "enter1" );
    puts( "enter number integers to be summed" );
    if( scanf("%d",&size) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number of integers to sum failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    
    //int arr1[size];
    puts("enter the integers, seperated by a space or newline");
    //int *ptr;
    int inputData[ size ];
    for( int i=0; i<size; i++ ) 
    {
        //scanf("%d",(ptr+i));
        if( scanf( "%d", inputData + i ) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for int data failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }   
    }
    
    for( int i=0; i<size; i++ ) 
    {
        sum += *( inputData+i );
    }
    
    printf( "'%d'", sum );
    return 0;
}
```